# How to access localized page properties in TYPO3 FLUID?

Tags: typo3, fluid

I want to access localized page properties in a Fluid template.

For example

```
{data.title}
```

But regardless of the chosen language the data array/object always gets the default language representation.

This can be simply reproduced by using

```
<f:debug>{data}</f:debug>
```

in the currently used FLUIDTEMPLATE on a multilingual page.

Typo3 obviously recognizes that the language has been changed once the **?L=1** querystring was appended because the data object debug shows additional properties/keys

```
_PAGES_OVERLAY => TRUE
_PAGES_OVERLAY_UID => '1' (1 chars)
_PAGES_OVERLAY_LANGUAGE => 1 (integer)
```

but the title remains in the default language.

Some Information about the system:

- Typo3 6.2.4
- Fluid 6.2.0 (Sys Standard)
- Extbase 6.2.0 (Sys Standard)

If it's relevant I want this to use direktly in the FLUIDTEMPLATE file, not in an Extbase Extension Fluid Template. So I don't have a Controller to do some custom queries and forward them to my the view.

Typoscript language configuration is simple two language standard and works otherwise

P.S. I'm just using the title in my question, because its available out of the box. My actual usecase is for several custom fields added to page and page_language_overlay by my own extenision. But as for this question you can ignore that fact.

Any help/hint appreciated.
Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

No idea why it doesn't work with `title` out of the box. But you need to configure the localized fields to override the default using `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageOverlayFields']`.

Documentation for this option can be found here: https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/blob/HEAD:/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php#l1099 or in install tool.
And as you can see, `title` is already there.

This option just defines overlays for `pages`. You have to follow TCA `l10n_*` properties (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html) to overwrite them in your extension. And for Extbase you need to take care about relations. Can't find the issue on forge yet.